# Consumer Producer

Tags: java, multithreading

ProdCom.java (driver class)

```
import static java.lang.System.out;


public class ProdCom{
    static int full = 50;
    static int mutx = 0;
    static int empty = 0;
    static int currentSize = 0;
   
    public static void acquire(){
        while (mutx == 1);
        
        mutx++;
        
    }
    
    public static void release(){
        mutx--;
    }
    
 
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Thread t = new Thread(new Producerr());
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Consumerr());
                
        t.start();
        t1.start();
    }
   
    
}
```

Producerr.java

```
class Producerr implements Runnable{
        
        
        public void wwait(){
            while (ProdCom.currentSize >= ProdCom.full){
                
            } 
            
        } public void signal(){
            ProdCom.currentSize++;
        }
        
        public void run(){
            do{
                this.wwait();
                
                ProdCom.acquire();
                
                out.println("Num elements" + ProdCom.currentSize);
                out.println("producing!");
                
                ProdCom.release();
                this.signal();
            } while (true);
        }
    }
```

Consumerr.java

```
class Consumerr implements Runnable{
        public void wwait(){
            while (ProdCom.currentSize <= 0){
                out.println("inside consumer wait: ");
                out.println("number of elements: " + ProdCom.currentSize);
            } 
            
        } public void signal(){
            ProdCom.currentSize--;
            
        }
        
      
        public void run(){
            do{
               
                this.wwait();
                ProdCom.acquire();
               
                out.println("Num elements" + ProdCom.currentSize);
                out.println("Consuming!");
                
                ProdCom.release();
                this.signal();
            } while (true);
        } 
    }
```

Above is my solution to the consumer-producer problem. The driver class `ProdCom` has variables `full`, `empty` and `mutx` for controlling  producer `t` and consumer `t1`'s access to the variable `currentSize` (Thus simulating the current number of items in a buffer). But when I run the code, the output seems to indicate t1 and t aren't taking turns to change `currentSize`, instead one of them repeats forever and gets stuck...I'm wondering why? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Java memory models allows threads to cache the values of variables, and different threads to have different caches. This means that the spin lock in `acquire` easily becomes an infinite loop: the thread in acquire may use the cached value `mutx = 1` and never read the updated value from main memory:

```
while (mutx == 1); // infinite loop even if another thread changes mutx
```

Another problem is that the `++` and `--` operators are not atomic: they read the value of the variable, modify it, and write it back. If two threads run `currentSize++` and `currentSize--` at the same time it is possible one of them is lost.

You can fix these problems by using an `AtomicInteger` object and its methods instead of `int`, for example in ProdCom:

```
static AtomicInteger currentSize = new AtomicInteger(0);
static AtomicInteger mutx = new AtomicInteger(0);

public static void acquire() {
    while (!mutx.compareAndSet(0, 1));
}

public static void release() {
    mutx.set(0);
}
```

Comment: I like the use of the `AtomicInteger` for `mutx` here. It is definitely the cleaner approach. But I leave it to the OP to improve the example code I've posted. Since the `currentSize` actually represents a more complex data structure, protecting it by a lockObject is probably a more generic approach (I think)

Answer (score 1):

I've improved your code a bit, and you'll notice that many of the concepts mentioned by Joni are considered.

ProdCom.java

```
import java.lang.*;

public class ProdCom{
    static final int FULL = 50;
    static final int EMPTY = 0;

    static volatile int mutx = 0;
    static volatile int currentSize = 0;
    static Object lockObject = new Object();
   
    public static void acquire(){
        /* since mutx is defined volatile, the spinlock works,
           but you reconsider this approach. There are cheaper
           methods of heating the room */
        while (mutx == 1);
        
        mutx++;
        
    }

    public static boolean isEmpty() {
        synchronized(lockObject) {
            if (currentSize <= EMPTY) return true;
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    public static boolean isFull() {
        synchronized(lockObject) {
            if (currentSize >= FULL) return true;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static int getCurrentSize() {
        synchronized(lockObject) {
            return currentSize;
        }
    }
    
    public static void release(){
        mutx--;
    }

    public static void incCurrentSize()
    {
        synchronized(lockObject) {
            currentSize++;
        }
    }
    
    public static void decCurrentSize()
    {
        synchronized(lockObject) {
            currentSize--;
        }
    }
    
 
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Thread t = new Thread(new Producerr());
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Consumerr());
                
        t.start();
        t1.start();
    }
   
    
}
```

Consumerr.java

```
import java.lang.*;

class Consumerr implements Runnable {

    public void wwait() {
        while (ProdCom.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("inside consumer wait: ");
            System.out.println("number of elements: " + ProdCom.getCurrentSize());
            try {
                /* we don't spinlock here */
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                /* do nothing */
            }
        } 
        
    }

    public void signal(){
        ProdCom.decCurrentSize();
        
    }
    
      
    public void run(){
        do{
            this.wwait();
            ProdCom.acquire();
               
            System.out.println("Num elements " + ProdCom.getCurrentSize());
            System.out.println("Consuming!");
            this.signal();
            
            ProdCom.release();
        } while (true);
    } 
}
```

Producerr.java

```
import java.lang.*;

class Producerr implements Runnable {

    public void wwait(){
        while (ProdCom.isFull()){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch(Exception e) { /* do nothing */ }
        } 

    }
    public void signal(){
        ProdCom.incCurrentSize();
    }

    public void run(){
        do {
            this.wwait();

            ProdCom.acquire();

            System.out.println("Num elements : " + ProdCom.getCurrentSize());
            System.out.println("producing!");
            this.signal();

            ProdCom.release();
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't a spinlock be used inside the `wwait` method?

Comment: It can be used, but it's a waste of CPU (and energy). You write that the currentSize simulates the state of a more complex structure (a Buffer). It is likely that changes to that data structure take some time. Maybe not 50ms, but it'll be a good idea to release the CPU while waiting for something to happen.